# PostgreSQL - update table using another table? (different database)

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 databases, let's call them `db1` and `db2`.
They both have the same table, called `mytable` but with different values. (same columns)

How can i take the values of `mytable` from `db1` and use them to update `mytable' in`db2`?

Comment: Have you tried foreign data wrapper?

Comment: No, what is that?

Comment: A way to connect from one Db to another and use its tables https://robots.thoughtbot.com/postgres-foreign-data-wrapper